# Anyway to read a .plist from a firefox add-on?

Tags: macos, firefox-addon, plist

Is there a pre-existing XPCOM guy that will let me interrogate a .plist file from Javascript, or do I need to use nsIFile and parse the XML myself?

(For background, there is a version number in a directory structure I don't control that I need to read from a .plist in order to be future-proof.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what a .plist is but I gather it's some sort of XML.

If you're parsing XML, don't use nsIFile directly, use this: [Parsing and serializing XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML). You might also like to use [E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/e4x).

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing what the parsing and serializing page said.  The .plist seems to be how one gets by on mac without a registry.  It's a manifest for app bundles... and other things.  I gather.